# Disk Optimization - SCAN algorithm in Java

Tags: java

I am currently trying to create a method named arrangeBySCAN which takes in the parameters of previous, current, and an array of sequence. The purpose of this method is to arrange inputs from a .properties file according to SCAN format in disk optimization. 
I am however getting an error:

> IllegalArgumentException

on the following line of code:

```
int scanArray1[] = Arrays.copyOfRange(tmp, 0, currentIndex); //line 17
```

I'm not an experienced programmer and any help would be appreciated.

Here's the following code.

```
    private int[] arrangeBySCAN(int previous, int current, int sequence[]){
        int direction = previous - current;
        int seqLength = sequence.length;
        int tmp[] = new int[seqLength];
        // If direction is less than 0, it is increasing
        // If direction is greater than 0, it is decreasing
        if (direction < 0) {
            Arrays.sort(tmp);
        }
        else if (direction > 0){
            Arrays.sort(tmp);
            Collections.reverse(Arrays.asList(tmp));
        }
        // Find the index position of the current cylinder after sorting
        int currentIndex = Arrays.asList(tmp).indexOf(current);
        // Split the sequence into two parts, taking the index of the current cylinder as reference
        int scanArray1[] = Arrays.copyOfRange(tmp, 0, currentIndex);
        int scanArray2[] = Arrays.copyOfRange(tmp, currentIndex, tmp.length);
        // Reverse first sequence
        Collections.reverse(Arrays.asList(scanArray1));

        // Append the first sequence onto the second sequence
        int scanArray[] = new int[scanArray1.length + scanArray2.length];
        System.arraycopy(scanArray1, 0, scanArray, 0, scanArray1.length);
        System.arraycopy(scanArray2, 0, scanArray, currentIndex ,scanArray2.length);
        return scanArray;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `IllegalArgumentException` is due to `currentIndex` being -1. The exception you get most likely has a message saying "0 > -1". `currentIndex` is -1 because you never put anything in your `tmp` array, so `indexOf` returns -1 unless `current` happens to be 0.